# Having trouble reading x12 data from pyx12 python library

Tags: python, x12

I'm having some trouble loading the x12 data from a file in order to parse and identify if it meets the criteria that we need. Here is what I have so far but I keep getting the error message `"invalid mode: 'U'"`

It seems like it might have to do with the mode being deprecated but I'm not entirely sure how to get around it. In their [github](https://github.com/azoner/pyx12/blob/master/pyx12/x12file.py) at line 308 it defaults to the U and adding a new variable in the x12reader portion errors out since it doesn't take 3 arguments.

Here is my code so far thinking it would read the file into the variable then grab the important aspects.

```
import pyx12.x12file
import os

src_file = source_file_name

try:
    if not os.path.isfile(src_file):
        print('Could not open file "%s"' % (src_file))
        exit
    src = pyx12.x12file.X12Reader(src_file)  <-- errors here 
    for seg in src:
        # seg.
        if seg.get_seg_id() == 'ST':
            print(seg)
            # for value in seg.values_iterator():
            #     print(value)
            print(seg.get_value('ST03'))

except pyx12.errors.X12Error:
    print('"%s" does not look like an X12 data file' % (src_file))
except Exception as E:
    print(E)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked at the source and "invalid mode: 'U'" comes from their use of python's regular `open()` with mode 'U' rather than one of those available, such as: 'w', 'r', 'rb', ...

However, as you can see a few lines above, this only happens if you pass the file as a string which represents its location. Alternatively you can provide an open file object, in which case this error shouldn't happen.

For instance:

```
with open(src_file) as f:
    src = pyx12.x12file.X12Reader(f)
```

(assuming those are non-binary files, otherwise you'd need to `with open(src_file, 'rb') ...`)